# Can I control a distance between two or more spheres over time while one is fixed?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to represent the movement of some parts of a molecule and divide it by criteria, I lready have the data and think I should use a driver to represent closely the distance I measured, while linking each sphere to each other with some sort of elastic ribbon.

As I am still new with blender, I do not know all options I have, I already tried armatures but have failed terribly, as it has way too parameters for me.

My problematic represented in images :
[image: distance measurment]

[image: more points]

[image: link without constraints]

*Edit I would like the distance to be visible (black bars) but if only the red dots linked by green lines are there, it's still very much what I could use.

Comment: can you show us how your data looks like?

Comment: It really is just a time-distance graph, I don't want this "simulation" to be exact, just to globally represent the tendencies I've analysed@Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you only want to move in one direction (e.g. y direction) you can

1. create two UVSpheres and 1 cylinder
2. move the cylinder in edit mode in that way, that the origin point is in the left UVSphere

[image]

3. Select the right circle vertices of the cylinder and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and select "Hook to new object".

[image]

4. add an object constraint to your new created empty from 3) like this:

[image]

and choose the right sphere as target.

Now you can move the right Sphere on the y direction and the cylinder/connection will follow along.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your detailed answer, I'll test this as soon as I can and come back to you

Comment: Ok the hook seem to be enough, I linked both ends to the respective sphere, and will try to network it out without making a mess. Thanks again

Comment: Please check the checkmark left to my answer if the answer helped you. Thank you.